# sending an url but staying on the same page ( php, codeigniter, javascript )

Tags: codeigniter

this is my situation. I'm writing an webinterface in codeigniter to send commands to a virtual server. these commands are passed through the browser in an url.

example : http://server.com/TgtSendIRCommand?id=UM-02&code=KEY_UP
this server then takes action and the web interface refreshes the screenshot.

i just want to have a bunch of links in html that send this command to the browser. 
But if i click the links, the user has to stay on the same page. So the command is sended but there is no other interaction.

i am using codeigniter.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This is where AJAX comes in.. did you tried it with JavaScript?

Comment: i have no idea how to, i'm very new to JavaScript. Have you got an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a view and copy this in your view:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="myBtn">Click here!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myBtn").click(function(){  
       $.get("http://server.com/TgtSendIRCommand?id=UM-02&code=KEY_UP ");        
     });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Not tested but something as above should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['http://localhost/profile.php'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $sess=$_SESSION["email"];
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname ="reg";
        if(!isset ($sess)) 
        { 
            header("Location:login.php");
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Just have to add some coding