# passing php variables to javascript function to use that variable as a parameter in url

Tags: codeigniter

i have a variable $lat and i need it to pass to javascript function show() where $lat is passed to the url through window.location.href.
I have searched everything but nothing seems to work. BTW i dont want to use ajax for this. can it be done with other methods? I am using php codeigniter.

Comment: `I have searched everything but nothing seems to work` what did not worked?

Comment: var lat = '<?php echo $lat;?>';-> this didn't work and trying to get value from hidden input field didnt work either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing php variable from controller to javascript function in the head of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405742/passing-php-variable-from-controller-to-javascript-function-in-the-head-of-a-vie)

Answer (score 0):

Without using Ajax, you can only pass that variable through your view. Imagine the following scenario:

```
function yourController()
{
  $data['lat'] = 'http://google.com';
  $this->load->view('yourView/index', $data);
}

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <script>
        function show()
        {
           window.location.href = '<?php echo $lat; ?>';
        }
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lat = '<?php echo $lat;?>';
show(lat);
function show(lat){
  location.href = 'something.com?latval='+lat;
}
```

Comment: are you sending url from controller to view and you want  to have it in js.

Comment: Actually i have several other javascript variables which i have passed to a link with window.location.href.....
now i need to add this $lat variable as a parameter to that link.
$lat variable was passed in current view from controller.

Comment: something like these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085388/sending-an-url-but-staying-on-the-same-page-php-codeigniter-javascript?rq=1 . do concat the lat value.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.